# Change port design in JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm trying to create graph using JointJS, where Link starts from output port od 1 element and can be connected with whole other element (or current element itself) - not only with input port.
My idea is to modify input port style, to cover element it belongs to, but I have problems to change port shape in any way, it's always a little circle on left side of element and none of my css works. 
Can someone give any advice?

Answer (score 2):

you can update the port attrib0utes as follows:

```
var a = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    attrs: {
        '.port-label': {
            fill: 'red'
        },
        // change position and size of the 'a' port
        '.inPorts .port0 circle': {
            r: 15,
          'ref-x': -20,
          'ref-y': 10,
          stroke: 'red',
          'stroke-width': 5
        }, 
        // change color on a single port 
        '.inPorts .port0 .port-label': {
            fill: 'blue',
        }
    },
    inPorts: ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
    outPorts: ['b']
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/43sthc6g/

However, you don't need to use ports to achieve this, you can connect to the whole element directly like this:

```
var a = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    size: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    position: { x: 300, y: 300 },
    attrs: {
        'rect': { magnet: true }
    }

}).addTo(graph);

var b = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    size: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    position: { x: 100, y: 100 },
    attrs: {
        'rect': { magnet: true }
    }
}).addTo(graph);

new joint.dia.Link({ source: { id: b.id }, target: { id: a.id } }).addTo(graph);
```

result: https://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/davLzsng/

Comment: What about jointjs v1?